# TeamCity Login issue (version 2017.2.3)

Tags: teamcity

We use TeamCity for Continuous Integration and today, when i updated my TeamCity to version 2017.2.3 (build 51047), it isn't allowing me to login using my regular username/password

When i try to use my username and password. I get below error:

```
Login failed in all authentication modules with messages:
Invalid login format: domain name is required
Incorrect username or password.
```

I cant get my head around this error? which domain name should i use? because from installing TeamCity (couple of years ago) till today upgradation, TeamCity has never asked me for any Domain Name. Does it has some of its own domain which i need to use?

I tried to find solution to my issue but couldn't find much available.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: do you use Active Directory and Domain Controller for login to TC?

Comment: No, i have always used just simple username and password to log into TC

Comment: how are you updated ? the TC saves credentials in the DB which located on DATA_DIR path. you should start restore process